# multiplication of exponentials for non commuting matrices

Tags: exponentiation, noncommutative-algebra

Is there any special condition for the following statement to be true for any $n \times n$ matrices?

$$
e^Ae^B=e^{A+B}=e^Be^A
$$

Is it always correct to say that

> the exponential product equals the sum of the exponentials

and that is why the multiplication of exponentials commutes: because matrix addition is commutative?

### Edit

From the answers I understand that

$$e^A e^B \neq e^{A+B}$$

when $A$ and $B$ do not commute.

But if I have two non commuting matrices $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ like in [this example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D%20times%20matrix%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D%20minus%20matrix%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D%20times%20matrix%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D), I see that their exponentials still commute from [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D)%20times%20%20matrixexp(%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D)%20minus%20%20matrixexp(%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D)%20times%20%20matrixexp(%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0%7D%7D)). (Edit2 - that WolframAlpha result was obviously wrong: those exponentials don't commute and the following inequality is true)

So is there an example of two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the following holds?

$$e^A e^B \neq e^B e^A $$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma , "A direct application of this identity"

Comment: @J.G. I think that you pointed me to the answer I was looking for: $e^A e^B = e^{A+B+1/2[A,B]}$ and therefore $e^A e^B = e^B e^A$, could you please confirm it with an answer if that holds true?

Comment: You realise $[A,\,B]$ is non-commutative, right?

Comment: @J.G. I was missing that part, thank you: you really *answered* my question (I guess that's more than a comment), now I see that $e^B e^A = e^A e^B e^{−[A,B]}$ provided—as always—that $[A,B]$ commutes with $A$ and $B$ - as it reads from this [appendix](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Book%3A_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fowler)/3%3A_Mostly_1-D_Quantum_Mechanics/Appendix%3A_Some_Exponential_Operator_Algebra)

Comment: By the way, the Kronecker Sum has the property $e^{A \oplus B} = $$e^A \otimes e^B$ as shown in this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709114/how-to-prove-ea-oplus-b-ea-otimes-eb-where-a-and-b-are-matrices), but I guess it is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if $AB=BA$, that is the matrices commute.  If not, this generally does *not* hold.  If $A,B$ do not commute but are Hermitian, then you get the [Golden-Thompson inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Inequalities_for_exponentials_of_Hermitian_matrices): $$tr ~e^{A+B}\le tr ~(e^A e^B)$$
Here, $tr$ denotes matrix trace.

Comment: Out of my *curiosity*, what about the *converse*? Are there any non-commuting matrices such that their exponentials commute? I think one can only find *operators* but not *matrices* such that, e.g.,  $[A,B] = 2πi$ or (any non zero number times the identity matrix), right?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ commute ($AB=BA$) then the equality holds. However, it does not hold in general. [Here are several counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute).

Comment: Out of my *curiosity*, what about the *converse*? Are there any non-commuting matrices such that their exponentials commute? I think one can only find *operators* but not *matrices* such that, e.g.,  $[A,B] = 2πi$ or (any non zero number times the identity matrix), right?